# Will changing a Cosmos DB container's indexing policy to the same policy consume resources?

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, azure-cosmosdb

I'm currently trying to determine if updating the indexing policy for a Cosmos DB container to the same policy will consume resources. I want to keep track of the indexing policy using a script in my CI process which updates the policy through Azure CLI in an Infrastructure as Code fashion. However, I want to avoid accruing any unnecessary resource costs that might result from running this script multiple times even when there are no changes in the policy from the last time it was run.

According to some of the [Microsoft Learn Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-policy#modifying-the-indexing-policy) for Cosmos DB.

> An update to the indexing policy triggers a transformation from the old index to the new one, which is performed online and in-place (so no additional storage space is consumed during the operation). The old indexing policy is efficiently transformed to the new policy without affecting the write availability, read availability, or the throughput provisioned on the container.

At first, I was thinking this sounded straight forward, the transformation shouldn't be necessary and shouldn't result in any resources being utilized. But I couldn't exactly think of a great way to test whether this would be true in the end.

A potential workaround I thought of might be to just maintain some kind of item within the container which describes the current version of the indexing policy and only apply the script if it contains a version different than the current value. I'd just have to remember to increment the version on the script each time I update it, but this solution seems a bit messy and potentially might miss updates due to developer error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redeploying an ARM template, Bicep or executing a script to create or update a Cosmos DB resource for the same container resource with the same index policy will not trigger a rebuild on the index.

To do so would cause havoc anyway because most users typically redeploy to do other things like change throughput or make other unrelated changes.

You can certainly create your own mechanism for managing and versioning your IAC, but not for this. Most just use regular version control.